# How to properly move content to center without making text center-aligned in Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

Basically, in bootstrap, I have my main page in two grids so that in scaling (aka. mobile-view), the content would move under each other, but I wanna move my text to the center of the grid (horizontally and vertically) without aligning the text to the center, but it's not achievable with the `d-flex` bootstrap function properly. [This is what I want to accomplish with my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y58Vk.png), and [this is what I have at the moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hmt3.png) (the navbar text sizes are what I want, although they are bigger in the 'I want' photo). Here's the code of what I have so far:

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #EECBD1;
    font-family: 'Jost', sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.heaven-logo {
    /* max-width: 50%; */
    height: auto;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.nav-link {
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 100%;
    color: #000;
    display: flex;
    padding-right: 15px;
    list-style: none;
}

.nav-link:hover {
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar-nav {
    margin-left: auto;
}

.landing-main-text {
    font-family: 'Jost', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 500%;
    line-height: 1.1;
    margin: none;
}

.landing-desc-text {
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 200%;
}

.macaron-image {
    width: 25rem;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Macaron Heaven</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <!-- CSS tag -->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Google fonts -->
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;300;400;500&family=Jost:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Saját css -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Navbar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand" id="navbar">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="img/logo.png" class="heaven-logo">
              </a>
              <div id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Választék</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Rólunk</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Elérhetőség</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- Landing page -->
        <div class="container-fluid" id="landpage">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
                    <p class="landing-main-text">Az igazi macaron.</p>
                    <p class="landing-desc-text">Édes, színes ínyencség, miből egy sosem elég.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
                    <img src="img/macaron-image.svg" class="macaron-image">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- JS tag -->
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `justify-content-center` on the Div for your wording and the Div for your image. Try this instead....

The Div with the image can have no `d-flex` and will only contain the `col` information that you detailed. I would say though, on the `<img>` class add `img-fluid`. This will make sure the image is always the full width of its parent Div.

The Div with the wording will have `d-flex align-items-stretch` to make sure both columns are the same height.

Then, inside the wording Div, wrap another basic Div around both paragraphs and in that new Div add `class="d-flex align-self-center"`. This is to center the new Div inside your existing column.

It is possible that the paragraphs will not wrap properly as you have more than one. If that turns out to be the case try also adding `flex-wrap` to the new inner Div so that it reads `class="d-flex align-self-center flex-wrap"`.